# Objects getting copied by reference and replacing all items in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I understand that people have faced this issue before and I have gone through the previous posts. 
I have an arrayList and I'm trying to add objects to it. During every add call, the same object reference is being copied. Though I have used the 'new' operator and am creating new objects. This is something basic and has worked previously when I create the object again during each iteration. 
Any help is much appreciated. 
Here is my code.

```
public List<Actor> readAllActors()
{
    String selectMovie = "SELECT * from ACTOR;";
    List<Actor> listOfActors = new ArrayList<Actor>();
    try {           
        statement = conn.prepareStatement(selectMovie);
        results = statement.executeQuery(selectMovie);      
                    Actor a = new Actor();
        while (results.next())
        {                  
                       a = getActorFromResult(results);
                       listOfActors.add(new Actor(a.getId(), a.getFirstName(), a.getLastName(), a.getDateOfBirth()));                               
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return listOfActors;    
}

private Actor getActorFromResult(ResultSet results) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int id = results.getInt("id");
    String fname = results.getString("firstName");
    String lname = results.getString("lastName");
    String dob = results.getString("dateOfBirth");

    Actor actor = new Actor(id, fname, lname, dob );        
    return actor;
}
```

I have tried printing the object in each iteration. It is fetching the right row from the table.. the new Actor() seems to have no effect in creating a new object reference!!

Comment: why don't you use "listOfActors.add(a)" instead of the line you are using there? If you want a new object with the same attributes, you may want to use the "clone" method.

Comment: How do you know it's the same object reference?

Comment: Your object allocations are ineffective, `listOfActors.add(getActorFromResult(results));` is sufficient. It's definitely not the same object here, because you allocate it in your method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine and can't pass the same reference all the time. You can check it via a == check of your listed objects.

You could refactor you code to

```
results = statement.executeQuery(selectMovie);      
while (results.next())
{          
    listOfActors.add(getActorFromResult(results));                    
}
```

as you're creating a new `Actor` and thus a new object with an own reference after fetching the result set. This will also make the code clearer here.

Also `return new Actor(id, fname, lname, dob );` will do the job in your result method. You're not using the self-descriptive local variable anyways.

**I suspect your problem lies in your database. Try querying it with a database tool.**

Comment: Hi Zhedar.. Logically it is supposed to work! I have corrected this before by creating a new object and returning! The database is returning unique actor objects everytime.. I have verified this by printing fields of the actor after this step:               a = getActorFromResult(results);
The only problem lies after the second iteration of arraylist.add().. The second object also replaces the first object!

Comment: @user1947288 So `listOfActors.size()` returns 1 although there's more than one iteration?

Comment: No the list size is 4(Because I have four rows in my table).. All four actor objects get added.. But they are all the same.. i.e they are all the last object that was added..

Comment: You may want to remove `ResultSet results` as a parameter, since you already defined into in your class. Normally this isn't a problem, but it's actually the last thing I could image... :/ (Also you're not closing the ResultSet, are you?)

Comment: Would closing the result set be a problem? I can see when I step through the code that the first object gets added normally to the list.. when the list.add(A) is called the second time.. both the objects are the second object.. 3rd time all 3 are the 3'rd object and so on...

Comment: Then your error may lie elsewhere, maybe same jre/compiler issue you're facing. I would recommend to take a break and try again later, maybe it's something, we both aren't seeing. ;)

Comment: Yupp I've taken a break after trying every possible way of returning an object !! :)

Comment: Just wanted to let u kNow I solved it!! My bad.. Actor.java all instance variables were declared static!!

Comment: Nice to know you found it, did not think about that though. :) So this code code was fine after all ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to change that line

`listOfActors.add(new Actor(a.getId(), a.getFirstName(), a.getLastName(), a.getDateOfBirth()));`

to that

`listOfActors.add(getActorFromResult(results));`

and delete  line

`a = getActorFromResult(results);`

Your references are for sure not the same, please check it in debugger.

Comment: I was returning listOfActors.add(getActorFromResult(results)) initially before I complicated the return statement! I have used the debugger to step through.. The getActorFromResult returns a unique object each time.. The code goes wrong in ArrayList.add()